# How to use Snappy Compression And Decompression in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, snappy

i am using following code for compression

```
     Configuration conf = new Configuration(); 
    conf.setBoolean("mapred.compress.map.output", true); 
conf.set("mapred.map.output.compression.codec","org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec");
```

using snappy algorithm. but while compressing an input file with some mb of data ( 70 to 100 mb) it compresses data with file size which is more than the input file and if i try it with input directory containing all types of file like(.jpg, .mp3, .mp4 etc..) with size 100 to 150 mb, it displays error as :

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x930c0000, 105119744, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 105119744 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/hduser/workspace/TestProject/hs_err_pid16619.log
```

As i am trying to compress and decompress data using snappy algorithm, please here suggest me , how do i compress data using sanppy algorithm with less space.

i am using

Ubuntu  13.10, 32 bit
Jdk 7   32 bit.
with hadoop-2.2.0

Comment: Your local machine is running out of memory, buy more ram :p

Comment: #Thomas, thanks for reply. i am getting compressed file size more than the input file, as i know after compression file size should be reduced. as you suggested will get more RAM.

Comment: You should also try to reduce the number of parallel mappers/reducers, or in YARN the reserved memory.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut , i cannot find any way to reduce number of mappers, as googled number of mappers depends on InputFormat, and we cannot control the number of mappers.. here.

Comment: There is no point compressing .jpg, .mp3, or .mp4 files with Snappy as they are already compressed formats.

Comment: I want to compress the directory which contains all types of files..